# Adding an .env file to a React project

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, api-key

I'm trying to hide my API Key for when I commit to GitHub, and I've looked through the forum for guidance, especially the following post:

*[How do I hide an API key in Create React App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699820/how-do-i-hide-api-key-in-create-react-app)*

I made the changes and restarted [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong—I added an `.env` file to the root of my project (I named it `process.env`) and in the file I just put `REACT_APP_API_KEY = 'my-secret-api-key'`.

I'm thinking it might be the way I'm adding the key to my `fetch` in *App.js*, and I've tried multiple formats, including without using the template literal, but my project will still not compile.

```js
performSearch = (query = 'germany') => {
    fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=${query}&client_id=${REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData => {
        this.setState({
            results: responseData.results,
            loading: false
        });
     })
     .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
     });
}
```

Comment: instead of `process.env` name it `.env.local or .env.process ` and keep it outside of src directory

Comment: Hi @RIYAJKHAN I've changed the file to .env.local and it's definitely outside the src directory, but I'm still getting REACT_APP_API_KEY is not defined :/

Comment: What fixed it for me was simply closing the terminal running my local dev server and re-running `npm run start`.

Comment: You can't hide secrets in a react app. See stackoverflow.com/a/46839021/4722345

Comment: DO NOT use this to store secrets. From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)...`WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your React app!

Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can view them by inspecting your app's files.`

Comment: You need to setup a server and use authentication like JWT in order to hide it. Read [this suggestion](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/1744#issuecomment-303112505) for more info.

Answer (score 394, accepted):

#### Four steps

1. `npm install dotenv --save`
2. Next, add the following line to your app.

   `require('dotenv').config()`
3. Then create a `.env` file at the root directory of your application and add the variables to it.

```
// contents of .env

REACT_APP_API_KEY = 'my-secret-api-key'
```

4. Finally, add `.env` to your `.gitignore` file so that Git ignores it and it never ends up on GitHub.

If you are using [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) (`create-react-app`) then you only need step 3 and 4, but keep in mind a variable needs to start with `REACT_APP_` for it to work.

Reference: *[Adding Custom Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)*

***Note*** - **You need to restart the application after adding a variable in the .env file.**

Reference: *[Using the dotenv package to create environment variables](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/using-dotenv-package-to-create-environment-variables-33da4ac4ea8f)*

Comment: need to restart application after adding variable in .env file .use "REACT_APP_"  before variable name if you create react application using "create-react-app".

Comment: where do I add ```require('dotenv').config()```? which file?

Comment: @aqteifan u don't need to add that snippet, but then .ENV files naming plays a vital role

Comment: @user2763557 the pattern I use is create a `.env.example` file where the definitions of the env keys are laid out. Then, you can copy the `.env.example` and create a `.env` file (in development and production) containing you valid values e.g. keys, base urls etc. You have to add the `.env` file to `.gitignore`.

Comment: only step 3 and 4 are relevant

Comment: keep in mind: all variables need to start with `REACT_APP_` to work. And also those variables are visible in the JS, so you should not put secret codes and private keys.

Comment: if your on `"react": "^16.13.1","react-dom": "^16.13.1","react-scripts": "3.4.1"` or higher and you you created the react application using `"create-react-app"` command then you don't need to install the dot env package anymore create a `.env` file out side your src folder (better at the project root) then name your variables with `REACT_APP_` as a prefix to the variable name eg: `REACT_APP_YOUR_VARIABLE` else it won't show up when you call it with `{process.env.REACT_APP_YOUR_VARIABLE}`

Comment: <title>%REACT_APP_WEBSITE_NAME%</title> only works in build time.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer can have so many upvotes. The secret will be embedded into the build in plain text! [See the big warning in the docs.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/.) Therefore step 4 is deluding: If you share your secret publicly in the build anyway, gitignoring the `.env` doesn't help that much. I'm wondering how many React apps in the wild already expose private keys...

Comment: I lost a day trying to find out why react couldn't read my environmental variable inside an .env file, that it didn't started with the prefix "REACT_APP_". Why this shitty restriction? I would never imagine that. Even an explicit call to dotenv module don't work and returns with error. I just found why with this post, thanx

Comment: So you spend the time to create this nice list of steps, but don't actually reveal how to use different environments. Considering we want to use one environment when testing locally vs making a production build. What are the file names? Will it just work or do you have to use a cmd line flag?

Comment: `.env` file needs to be in UTF-8 format

Comment: This accepted answer needs to be corrected. You simply cannot put secret keys in REACT_APP as it makes it accessible to the end user in plain text

Answer (score 252):

This solution does **not require** any extra packages.

#### Step 1 [ReactDocs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

In the above documentation they mention export in Shell and other options, and the one I'll attempt to explain is using **.env** file

1.1 Create Root/.env

```
#.env file
REACT_APP_SECRET_NAME=secretvaluehere123
```

Important notes: it ***must*** start with **REACT_APP_**.

1.2 Access the ENV variable

```
# App.js file or the file you need to access ENV
<p>print env secret to HTML</p>
<pre>{process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_NAME}</pre>

handleFetchData() { // access in API call
  fetch(`https://awesome.api.io?api-key=${process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_NAME}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
}
```

1.3 [Build Env Issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3568#issuecomment-352135847)

After I did step 1.1|2, it was not working, but then I found the above issue/solution. React reads/creates env when it is built, so you need to run **npm run start** every time you modify the .env file, so the variables get updated.

Comment: I was missing this `REACT_APP_` thank you. No other person mentioned it.

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason. I get `undefined`

Comment: @Si8 could you expand on you error/process. Which step you got `undefined`, did you restarted the app after adding a new variable to .env see 1.3

Comment: @T04435 thanks for this answer mate worked like charm `REACT_APP_` is the key here. Also how can i configure for different servers i have dev/beta/production do i need to have different env files for each server?

Comment: @KannanT You will need `.env.[ENVIRONMENT]`

Comment: @T04435 I already have mate what I was referring is do I need I have different.env files for each server?

Comment: @KannanT I think each server should have it onw .env
DEV server --> .env.development
PROD server --> .env.produciton

Comment: You need to restart your app, stop the running app and run npm start again

Comment: name the file ".env" and not "config.env" or anything. This fixed the 'undefined' for me.

Comment: I have tried everything. `process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY` says `undefined`.

Comment: For those who are getting `undefined` it is necessary to **restart the application**! This way react-script will save the value of the environment variable

Answer (score 133):

There is a now simpler way to do that.

Just create the *.env.local* file in your root directory and set the variables there. In your case:

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY = 'my-secret-api-key'
```

Then you call it in your JavaScript file in the following way:

```
process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
```

React have supported environment variables since *react-scripts@0.5.0*. You don't need an external package to do that.

*[Adding Development Environment Variables In .env](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env)*

*Note: I propose *.env.local* instead of *.env* because *create-react-app* adds this file to *gitignore* when creating the project.

Files priority:

npm start: .env.development.local, .env.development, .env.local, .env

npm run build: .env.production.local, .env.production, .env.local, .env

npm test: .env.test.local, .env.test, .env (note .env.local is missing)

More information: *[Adding Custom Environment Variables](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)*

Comment: Proper naming did the job for me. I used .env.dev and React fell back to .env as it was looking for .env.development

Comment: and one tip is restart server to work well

Comment: also do not use any quotes or spaces in the variable definition REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY=qweqwew88754

Comment: The "proper naming", as mentioned by @Omnibyte, can be referenced here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used

Answer (score 75):

**Steps to use environment variables in a CREATE REACT APP (Without dotenv package)**

- Create a new file called `.env` in the **root** folder of the project (**NOT** **inside src** folder but one level up. Remember, it should be at the same level as package.json (**THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT!!**)
- Define your variables like so (Note that every variable you define should start with REACT_APP_)

  Example : `.env file`

  `REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY=8Sh9ZLwZevicWC-f_lmHvvyMu44cg3yZBU`

  Note: You **don't** have to enclose the value in `"" or ''`
- Now you can use the variable in any of your components like so

  `const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY`

  The name should match the key given in the `.env` file
- Now before you try this out, **always remember to restart the local server**. Once you run `npm start` it works. This step applies whenever you make changes to the `.env` file. We generally forget this step so it might not work.
- Optionally, check if `.env` entry is present in `.gitignore` file. If the entry of `.env` exists in `.gitignore` then your `.env` file will not be pushed to github(This is the reason why we use `.env` in the first place).

Comment: I think restarting the project app is necessary after following this process.

Comment: Should it be possible to generate .env file when running docker-compose up?

Answer (score 51):

#### Webpack Users

If you are using [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack), you can install and use the `dotenv-webpack` plugin. To do that, follow steps below:

Install the package

```
yarn add dotenv-webpack
```

Create a `.env` file

```
// .env
API_KEY='my secret api key'
```

Add it to the `webpack.config.js` file:

```
// webpack.config.js
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv()
  ]
  ...
};
```

Use it in your code as

```
process.env.API_KEY
```

For more information and configuration information, visit *[dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack)*.

Comment: if you're using webpack-devserver you won't see changes until you restart it.

Comment: @Aminu Kano could you please explain me what's the point of using this approach if the api-key is still visible if I view the bundle.js file online in sources?

Comment: @LinasM. yeah sure, but what do you mean by "online"?

Comment: Well, maybe I formulated my question in a not very precise way. I mean I set up all this process.env.API_KEY in my application and everything works fine on a localhost and if I push changes to the gitHub, the api key is not visible. But if I push my application to Heroku, it doesn't work, because Heroku cannot see the api key. So, I had to to undo all the changes in order for an application to work. So I don't see the benefits how can I make use of this approach

Comment: @LinasM. Okay I understand what you mean, the bundle.js is created when you generate the production build, and the API-key should definitely be visible in it. The benefit here is that you can share the source via "GitHub" without exposing the secret keys, and the generated and gitignored production build deployed to "Heroku". Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 37):

#### 1. Create the **.env** file on your root folder

Some sources prefer to use `.env.development` and `.env.production`, but that's not obligatory.

#### 2. The name of your VARIABLE -must- begin with REACT_APP_YOURVARIABLENAME

It seems that if your environment variable does not start like that, you will have problems.

#### 3. Include your variable

To include your environment variable, just put `process.env.REACT_APP_VARIABLE` in your code.

*You don't have to install any external dependency*

Comment: I do the same thing but it shows undefined in console

Comment: If you are getting the values as undefined, recompile again.

Comment: after recompile still getting undefined. `console.log('process', process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL);`

Comment: Make sure you have the .env file in your root folder(same place where you have your package.json) and NOT in your src folder.

Comment: This is key: `The name of your VARIABLE -must- begin with REACT_APP_YOURVARIABLENAME`

Comment: The name of your VARIABLE -must- begin with REACT_APP_YOURVARIABLENAME. This is important Line. Thank you 

Answer (score 18):

1. Install `dotenv` as devDependencies:

   ```
   npm i --save-dev dotenv
   ```
2. Create a `.env` file in the root directory:

   ```
   my-react-app/
   |- node-modules/
   |- public/
   |- src/
   |- .env
   |- .gitignore
   |- package.json
   |- package.lock.json.
   |- README.md
   ```
3. Update the `.env` file like below & **REACT_APP_** is the compulsory prefix for the variable name.

   ```
   REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8000
   REACT_APP_API_KEY=YOUR-API-KEY
   ```
4. [ *Optional but Good Practice* ] Now you can create a configuration file to store the variables and export the variable so can use it from others file.

   For example, I've create a file named `base.js` and update it like below:

   ```
   export const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;
   export const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
   ```
5. Or you can simply just call the environment variable in your JS file in the following way:

   ```
   process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL
   ```

Comment: How do you differentiate between dev and prod environments when using just a single `.env` file? Im aware we need to create `.env.development` and `.env.prod` files, but how do we differentiate between them using your method?

Comment: @ameyaraje Basically, we ignore the `.env` file at our `.gitignore`. So, at the deployment, we just copy the `.env` file to our server and just change the **BASE_URL** and other necessary values. In this way, when it needs to deploy the latest code, we just pull from the git master and deploy it. We do not think about the `.env` as we are ignoring it and set it in our server at the very beginning. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I want to explain well how to solve this problem to prevent the `undefined` issues:

- First, adding development environment variables in `.env`  is available with `react-scripts@0.5.0` and higher. This means you do not have to install anything .
- Second, create your `.env` file or `.env_developement` file or whatever and place your variable, but, and this is the big but, add `REACT_APP_` to each variable name, for example, `REACT_APP_API_KEY= "secret_key_here"`. Without adding `REACT_APP_`, you will get the `undefined` issue.
- Now, you can simply use this variable: `process.env.REACT_APP_VARIBALE_NAME`. For example: `const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY`.
- Finally, we solved this miserable situation .

Answer (score 10):

You have to install **npm install env-cmd**

Make .env in the root directory and update like this & **REACT_APP_** is the compulsory prefix for the variable name.

```
REACT_APP_NODE_ENV="production"
REACT_APP_DB="http://localhost:5000"
```

Update package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Comment: Doing this results in a terminal error: `'env-cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`.

Answer (score 7):

If in case you are getting the values as `undefined`, then you should consider restarting the Node.js server and recompile again.

Answer (score 6):

The everyone got undefined the solution is put your *.env* file in the root directory, such as:

- project-name/
- src
- .env

***Don’t*** create it in the *src* Folder. Create it in the root directory of your app.

It think you created the file in the *src* folder, because I also created it there only... Then only did I realise it was wrong, so I created the .env file in the outer of src. It will work.

Comment: What do you mean by *"The everyone got undefined"*? It is incomprehensible.

Comment: @PeterMortensen why do you make unnecessary edits for all our answers here? I see that all the answers have your name as an editor (including mine but I just declined your edit as it was unnecessary)

Comment: @Deepak Aravind, you could go and do a Rollback if you don't like the edit

Answer (score 3):

You have to run `npm start` again once you set up the environmental variable. That was the missing part for me. The *.env* variables do not get updated on auto reloading.