# Can't access variable key inside .env (dotenv package React)

Tags: reactjs, api, authentication, environment-variables, dotenv

So I'm trying to understand how to use .env to secure my api key & data for my login auth. I've followed the process of the dotenv package and the stackoverflow [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579028/adding-an-env-file-to-react-project).

What I did:

1. I installed the dotenv package

2. In my rootfolder, I added a .env with only one line:

```
API_AUTH=http://myapilink.com
```

3. In my App.js, I added following line:

```
require('dotenv').config()
console.log(process.env.API_AUTH)
```

However, console.log returns 'undefined', why is that? What have I missed?

Comment: Did you generate your project using create-react-app?

Comment: I believe I did. I'm currently testing this on a react app I've been working on for a month now. But at the time, I followed Reacts guideline to create my react app

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to prefix your environment variables with `REACT_APP_`. See [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables).

> **Note**: You must create custom environment variables beginning with
>   `REACT_APP_`. **Any other variables except `NODE_ENV` will be ignored** to
>   avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could
>   have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require
>   you to restart the development server if it is running.

So instead of just `API_AUTH` it would be `REACT_APP_API_AUTH` instead.

And it will be exposed to your app as `process.env.REACT_APP_API_AUTH`.

Comment: After changing the variable name with the REACT_APP_ prefix, I still get undefined. However, I now `console.log(process.env)` to see what that returns and get the following: `Object
NODE_ENV: "development"
PUBLIC_URL: ""
__proto__: Object` I don't know if that helps.

Comment: @CédricBloem Did you restart your server after changing it? If that doesn't work, try changing your `.env` to `.env.development` and restart it again.

Comment: I did and it worked. Can't believe the "have you tried turning it on and off again" did it :) Thanks!!

Comment: @CédricBloem You don't need `dotenv` when working with CRA. It is bundled there anyways.

Comment: Yup, tried and tested solution for every computer problems.:). And you're welcome.

Comment: what if I'm using firebase as API. I tried I can't access it. it says `undefined`

Comment: @MichaleRezene I haven't tried that setup so unfortunately I can't answer your question.

Comment: Okay thank you for letting me know please leave a link if you find something related to my question thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Dotenv only works on server side. It needs an environment to store the variables. Here, we extract the content of the .env file and reduce it to an Object and pass it to Webpack's DefinePlugin allowing us later usage (process.env.API_AUTH):

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

module.exports = () => {
  const env = dotenv.config().parsed,
    envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
      prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
      return prev;
    }, {});

  return {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys)
    ]
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But apparently the mistake I made was forgetting to use the 'REACT_APP_' prefix for my variables.

Comment: In that one, you do not need the prefix.

Comment: Env variables were easy in #React App done with CRA. But, I faced the issue doing with #webpack and it was resolved with your solution. 
However, there is the #EnvironmentPlugin, which is equivalent to #DefinePlugin but with lesser code.
[Reference](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/)