# Setting up ENV Variables Without create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

What would be the process of setting up ENV variables to work in your react project when your react project isn't built using create-react-app, and has no backend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer. Quoted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53844967/2853450) by [Aminu Kano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6820579/aminu-kano).

> **Webpack Users**
>
> If you are using webpack, you can install and use
>   dotenv-webpack plugin, to do that follow steps below:
>
> Install the package
>
> `yarn add dotenv-webpack OR npm i dotenv-webpack`
>
> ```
> // .env 
> API_KEY='my secret api key' Add it to webpack.config.js file
> ```
>
> // webpack.config.js const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
>
> ```
> // webpack.config.js
> const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
>
> module.exports = {
>   ...
>   plugins: [
>     new Dotenv()
>   ]
>   ...
> };
> ```
>
> Use it in your code as
>
> ```
>  process.env.API_KEY
> ```
>
> For more information and configuration
>   information, visit [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack)

Comment: To be clear, by "setting up env variables", you meant how to load them from a file in your project? Also keep in mind that create-react-app only makes prefixed env vars (`REACT_APP_...`) available at runtime. You probably don't want every variable in your frontend bundle.

Comment: Yes that's right. This app is just for my portfolio, and I don't intend to hook up a backend, so it's not imperative to hook up a backend just to fully obscure the data. Unlike my last project where I used create-react-app (which already had dotenv built in behind the scenes) I opted this time around to create the webpack config from scratch. Just wasn't sure how to set it up to get the same functionality I was used to i.e. loading the API keys from env files.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

```
yarn add dotenv-webpack
```

Step 2: on webpack.config.js file:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv()
  ]
  ...
};
```

Last step: create .env file & put system variable in it:

```
URL=something.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can you a **.bashrc** file in linux to add any environment variable you want to use in the program.

```
Variable=<value>
```

you can just add variables and corresponding values and then you save and source the bashrc file using **source abc.bashrc** and then those variables will be available in the envrionment for the current terminal.
You can use this file in any programming language where you can read the environment variables.