# how to use .env file in a react js with typescript project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have a react js project , but with typescript. I understand we can create .env file and have some configuration defined as such,

.env file

```
REACT_APP_SOME_CONFIGURATION = "some value"
```

and use it in the code , without importing anything , like below

```
const configValue = process.env.REACT_APP_SOME_CONFIGURATION
```

I tried this set up in my project , and it didn't work. is it because it is typescript? how to use .env file in such scenario.

Comment: `process.env` does not exist on front end, you can use it only in your node backend

Comment: This is not true
We use it also  in  Frontend

Comment: @yoel are you sure about it? we had issue with similar case in our project because FE (react) could not consume process.env. what am i missing?

Comment: @YakirFitousi see here
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: @yoel wow, didnt know about it all.. thanks for the info! :)
BTW, is it only for `create-react-app` ?

Comment: I not sure, Maybe it's related to react-scripts@ library

Comment: @YakirFitousi hey yakir see here https://www.react-israel.co.il/%d7%a9%d7%99%d7%9e%d7%95%d7%a9-%d7%91%d7%9e%d7%a9%d7%aa%d7%a0%d7%99-%d7%a1%d7%91%d7%99%d7%91%d7%94/
OR here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59244254/9161478

Comment: @YakirFitousi it uses the Webpack Define plugin to make certain `process.env` variables available to the client-side code

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In TypeScript, you need to set the return value so if this string did so

```
const configValue : string = process.env.REACT_APP_SOME_CONFIGURATION
```

OR

```
const configValue: string = (process.env.REACT_APP_SOME_CONFIGURATION as string);
```

Comment: you're a life savior

Comment: the variable is possible undefined.

Answer (score 8):

You can add this to your `react-app-env.d.ts` file

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
       //types of envs
        NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production' | 'test';
        PUBLIC_URL: string;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update on March 2021:**
With React 17 and typescript, you don't need to set the return the 'configValue' value, just use the env variable like you did before.
My .env file like this

```
REACT_APP_STRING=some_string_dont_have_quotation_mark
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change this to a string or Undefined for a failing scenario like so

`const configValue : string | undefined  = process.env.REACT_APP_SOME_CONFIGURATION`