# Hiding the API key in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-scripts

We have an application that uses an API key (Accesstoken). We would like to hide the API key in a .env file.

We have gone through the following steps.

1. Created a .env file in the source folder (with the .gitignore)
2. Added in the .env
   REACT_APP_ACCESSTOKEN  = pk.ffe1Ijo.......
3. In the terminal added the npm install dotenv
4. Added the into our map.component file -
   import dotenv from 'dotenv'
   dotenv.config()
   const accessToken = process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESSTOKEN;
5. Added to webpack.config.js -

   externals: ["fs"],
   resolve: {
   extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
   },

Now we get the error message in the web browser console that fs is undefined. Or that the Acesstoken is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [create-react-app documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/), unless you're creating toy apps, **it's not a good idea** to store secret keys in your React app.

*But*, in case you really need to:

If you're using create-react-app, there's no need to install a separate dotenv library, as it's supported out of the box.

Otherwise, `dotenv-webpack` is probably something you can try. See this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59243719/setting-up-env-variables-without-create-react-app).

Comment: Thank you, we ran the npm i dotenv-webpack command and then amended the webpack.config.js (as shown on the link) and it worked.