# Adding an .env file to React Project not working

Tags: reactjs, react-boilerplate

I am trying to add `.env` file and variables but I am unable to access any variable. I am using [React Biolerplate Code](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate).

I am following this [React Docs File](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).

I have added one `.env` file in my root folder like this:

```
REACT_APP_SECRET_NAME=secretvaluehere123
```

And I am trying to access this using this code:

```
<small>You are running this application in <b>{process.env.NODE_ENV}</b> mode.</small>
```

I am getting NODE_ENV as development but when I am trying to access:

```
 REACT_APP_SECRET_NAME
```

I can't access it.

Mine react boilerplate is using:

```
cross-env  NODE_ENV=development
```

in the start command.

I removed (cross-env  NODE_ENV=development) from package.json but it is not working. I tried solutions from this answer: [Possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579028/adding-an-env-file-to-react-project).

According to [React Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) it should work. I want to add api_url for local it should be x and for the production, it should be y:

Comment: do process.env. REACT_APP_SECRET_NAME

Comment: Tried but not working

Comment: this might help you   https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/1250

Answer (score 1):

The following [issue](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/2208) from React Boilerplate seems to suggest a working solution:

1. Install [env-cmd](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd), a node module
2. Update your start script to use it:

```
  {
    start: "cross-env NODE_ENV=development env-cmd node server"
  }
```

This should work if your .env is in the root folder as you've said.
Otherwise, you can specify the path of .env by doing so

```
  {
    start: "cross-env NODE_ENV=development env-cmd -f ./custom/path/.env node server"
  }
```

Comment: Not working I am getting error:  > cross-env NODE_ENV=development env-cmd .env node server

spawn .env ENOENT

Comment: Is it possible to show your project file structure in your question?

Comment: I've updated my answer by digging a bit more in the doc, can you check if it works now?

Comment: It is just a react boilerplate code I am adding .env file in the root of react boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to access your `.env` variables inside `index.html`, if so then syntax is a bit different that in `render` function. Try to access it like this.

```
%REACT_APP_SECRET_NAME%
```

Comment: No, I am trying to access inside a component.

Comment: From the answer you have mentioned, did you try to install `dotenv` package and import it to your component?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking at two types of React starters:

- [React Boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate)
- [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

These aren't the same. I don't know React Boilerplate, but I'm not sure if they provide the same environment variables strategy with `.env` files as Create React App does.

Maybe have a look at the [dotenv Node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and perhaps you can add that to your project. I think (not 100% sure) that Create React App uses the same one.

Comment: In package.json they are using: (    "start": "cross-env  NODE_ENV=development node server",) They are using cross-env

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have everything right. Just remember to restart your development server every time you change information in your `.env` file.

Also, your `.env` file needs to be in the root directory of your react app. You can find all this information in the [React Docs - **Adding Development Environment Variables In `.env`**](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env)