# How do I configure my React-Node App so I can deploy it to Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, deployment

So I've built a simple MERN app using create-react-app, that I want to deploy to Heroku.  I build the front end in a client folder operating on localhost:3000, that sends requests to my express sever as a proxy to localhost:5000. My file structure is as follows:

```
+client
   |
   +-node_modules
   +-public
   +-src
     |
     +-components
        +-App.js
        +-index.js
//server
+-models
+-node-modules
+-package-lock.json
+-package.json
+-server.js
```

And I've set up the proxy in my `package-json` like this:   `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",`

So my main question is this: **How do I configure my API endpoints for deployment?**

At the moment, they're structured like this:

API call from react component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/all-cafes")
      .then((cafe) => {
        setCafe(cafe.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }, [])
```

Express function on server.js

```
app.get('/api/all-cafes', (req,res) => {
    Cafe.find()
    .then((result) => {
        res.send(result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

My other question is  **what is the role of the .env file, and will I need to make one in order to solve this?**

I've had a helpful suggestion saying that I can run the front end and back end on different servers, and adjust the code depending on whether it is in development or production, using the following code:

```
const prefix = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? "http://heroku_app_address" : "http://localhost:5000"
function getUrl(relativeUrl) {
   return prefix + "/" + relativeUrl;
}

fetch(getUrl('api/all-reviews'));
```

But I'm not sure how to implement this, whether I need a .env file, and if so, what to put in said file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.env` file helps you specifiy certain credentials or endpoints that are either going to change based on deployment environment (`dev`,`qa`,`prod` may have differewnt API endpoints), or you want to provide certain secret keys or configurations, which otherwise should not be part of your code repository (`clientSecret` etc).

The [create-react-app.dev/docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) has detailed explanation to these.
If you have not bootstraped your app using `create-react-app` then you can use `dot-env` npm package. The steps are detailed here: [Stack overflow :Adding an .env file to React Project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49579700/7306148)