# process.env.API_KEY is undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, dotenv

I am building a small application in react using firebase. I tried to put my firebase api key `API_KEY=somekey` in .env file which is in the root folder but when I use the process.env.API_KEY, I get an error in browser console shown in the picture below.

[image]

However, I have copied my api-key correctly in .env. what else could be the problem ?

Is there any configuration to be done in package.json before I use the process.env.API_KEY ?

Comment: You won't be able to access that, It's not available on the browser.

Comment: okay. so what else could be causing the application to crash. without the .env it works  properly and I am looking to upload it on github and with .env it ouputs an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hy, here is the documentation explaining how to use env variables in react: [link here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).

You must name your env variable `REACT_APP_API_KEY` in order to use it inside your react project.

You can also check this response: [response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579028/adding-an-env-file-to-react-project) .

Comment: Thank you @Raphael Escrig. it works prefectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using webpack try changing webpack config. Check doc [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/)

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const config = require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  // some config
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(config.parsed),
  ],
};
```

**OR**

You can use steps suggested [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

> Your project can consume variables declared in your environment as if
> they were declared locally in your JS files. By default, you will have
> NODE_ENV defined for you, and any other environment variables starting
> with REACT_APP_.

Answer (score 0):

as Raphael Escrig commented, set `API_KEY=somekey` to `REACT_APP_API_KEY=somekey` in .env file and call with process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY

> Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require you to restart the development server if it is running.