# React: environment variables undefined?

Tags: reactjs

Simple question,

I have the following environment variables:

`REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:1234`

Although this evaluates to undefined?

`console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL)`

Using create-react-app, from their documentation this is all I need to do? .env file is in the root directory, react even re-compiled when I changed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding an .env file to React Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579028/adding-an-env-file-to-react-project)

Comment: No, this question seems to be struggling to compile, my application compiles fine its just undefined.

Comment: Did you try to restart server?

Comment: @ShivamJha I have tried this yes, I've even rebuilt it, still no luck :(

Comment: Where did you **declared** these vars?

Comment: These are declared in a .env file in the root directory.

Comment: So, did you manage?

Comment: Hi, did any of the advice below help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to include your environment variables in global process.env. For this you can use some sort of package like dotenv.
This blog link would be helpful. https://trekinbami.medium.com/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5

Comment: No need for dotenv in create-react-app. I don't think this is anything to do with what I am doing, and this article is over 3 years old...

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `.env` file in your **root** folder (same as where `package.json` is) and not in `/src`. Then double check that you have restarted the server (kill the npm start and start again). If it's not that, you will have to share more information, because it doesn't seem to be anything wrong in the few bits of information you have shared.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some screenshots? It seems to work fine for me. Please see the below screenshots.

[image: Console Log]

[image: Directory Structure]

[image: Browser output]

Answer (score 0):

inside your app can you try to console.log it like this?

```
const {REACT_APP_API_URL} = process.env;

console.log(REACT_APP_API_URL)
```

Grabbed from here:
https://adostes.medium.com/using-environment-variables-in-a-react-application-ac3b6c307373