# Use Variable to define host and pass it to Image tag with image file name in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I m trying to pass host URL like this `http://localhost:1337` from one central file to all the image tags in all components. Currently I am able to render my images like this below.

```
<img
   style={{ height: "212px" }}
   src={`http://localhost:1337${props.data.image1.url}`}
   alt="new"
/>{" "}
```

Would love to achieve something like this below -

```
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:1337' //in one random file like .env in NodeJS at root
```

and all my Image tags get Images from there
Currently doing this way inside one component and it works.

```
export default function Home(props) {
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:1337';  
return(  
<img
style={{ height: "212px" }}
   src={`http://localhost:1337${props.data.image1.url}`}
   alt="new"
/>{" "})
...rest of the code here
)
}
```

Currently its throwing error. Something wrong with my Syntax.
Note: My images are in cloud and not in Public Folder which I could reference like process.env.PUBLIC ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Currently its throwing error. Something wrong with my Syntax."* - What is the exact error and what exact code does it refer to?

Comment: Undefined. Running with Strapi.  404 Not Found.  "http://localhost:3000/undefined/uploads/wrsg_main_logo_b44ee55d22.svg". It should be "http://localhost:1337/uploads/wrsg_main_logo_b44ee55d22.svg"

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a syntax error.  How are you importing `API_URL` into that file?  How are you exporting it from the file where it's defined?  Also, when you say *"in one random file like .env"* do you mean it's specifically in the `.env` file?  That doesn't look like how one would define environment variables.  The comment also says *"in NodeJS"*, does that mean this is a **server-side** environment variable?  How is React accessing this value?  There are a lot of unclear details here.

Comment: @David So I have not defined it yet in an .env file like we do in a NodeJS file. I am using React with Strapi CMS. I defined a variable in the in function like this - export default function Club(props) {
  const STRAPI_BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:1337'; ... I know it does not work that way. Hence trying to figure out the correct way to provide this variable throughout all the components from a central file.

Comment: So you define a `const` called `STRAPI_BASE_URL` and then try to use one called `API_URL`?  Those are two different names.  You'll need to use the value that was defined.

Comment: @David my bad. I did that. It works inside component. Image is coming up. One last thing, is there a way to defined this variable at the root variable so that I can consume it in all my components. Would be really thankful.

Comment: Well, you could define the `const` in a file of constants somewhere in your code and [export it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) to be imported anywhere else in your code.  Another alternative could be to [use environment variables in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49579028/328193).

Answer (score -2):

```
<img
   style={{ height: "212px" }}
   src={API_URL + props.data.image1.url}
   alt="new"
/>
```

Try this way!