# How can I fixed my problem"FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)."

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

My environment variable is ok. No comas and name mistakes but they given me error like "FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)". How can I fixed it. Please Help me...

This my .env file

```
REACT_APP_apiKey=AIzaSyBWobnhbdeMdNpXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
REACT_APP_authDomain=XXXXX.firebaseapp.com
REACT_APP_projectId=XXXX
REACT_APP_storageBucket=XXXXX.appspot.com
REACT_APP_messagingSenderId=4997390XXXXX
REACT_APP_appId=1:4997390XXXXX:web:cc7bc80aa1bdb78fXXXXXX
REACT_APP_measurementId=G-M1XDXXXXXX
```

This my firebase config file

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_apiKey,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_authDomain,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_projectId,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_messagingSenderId,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_appId,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_measurementId,
};

when I debugging firebaseConfig object

console.log(firebaseConfig.apiKey);  ==========> undefined 
console.log(firebaseConfig.authDomain);  ==========> undefined 
console.log(firebaseConfig.projectId);  ==========> undefined 
console.log(firebaseConfig.storageBucket); ==========> undefined 
console.log(firebaseConfig.measurementId); ==========> undefined 
console.log(firebaseConfig.appId); ==========> undefined 
console.log(firebaseConfig.measurementId); ==========> undefined
```

client side given error this "FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579028/adding-an-env-file-to-react-project#comment110254072_49579028

Comment: Hmm I see 
now my terminal restart again then my firebaseConfig object get that value..That's Awesome

Answer (score 0):

When you get in undefined  from firebaseConfig object value of keys. And they given a error like FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key). but your environment variable name and `process.env.[environment variable name]` and you had create a .env file root directory but stll they given same error.

The Answer is ..
You have to do right now, your terminal again restart when you still the same error..

this solution is worked my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should create the root file .env.local
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVf3U.png)

Comment: Yep ! I had created a .env file in root directory but still given me error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).