# How to use dotenv in react firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, dotenv

I am trying to set some environment variables in react firebase config variables. But it does not work. Now I want to know how to do the work? Mainly I want the firebase config variable set in dotenv variable.

Comment: [Adding an .env file to React Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579028/adding-an-env-file-to-react-project)

Comment: Can you share your actual .env ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can get an idea here - [Adding Firebase to React](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/react-part-time-react-track/react-with-nosql-part-1/adding-firebase-to-react). If you are having some problem in your .env file, please provide some code.