# Why I get UNDEFINED from ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE in REACT App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

Unfortunately, it's a pretty simple question, but I can't find the answer.

**Don't have an access to environment variables in some file.**

I use create-react-app (^16.11.0)

- file .env in the root folder near package.json
- variable declared as **REACT_APP_API=http://localhost:4000**
- call variable as process.env.REACT_APP_API
- the server has been restarted many times

I have an access to the variable in some folder but in another don't.

below link to files structure

[workflow structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sNGN.png)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding an .env file to React Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579028/adding-an-env-file-to-react-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM WAS FOUND!**
As often happens, the reason is funny.

When typing process.env.REACT_APP_API, my IDE automaticlly added an import at the top of the file

```
import process from "process";
```

That's why i can't access to process.env. in one specific file.

Import removed, problem solved