# docker build doesnt take changes .env in consideration

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

i have been trying to make a CI-CD pipline for a project i have 2 backends one is deployed on `http://141.9*.*****:8800/` and the other one is depolyed on `vps-a******.*******:8800`(some of the server links are hidden for security reasons)

anyway in `.env` i have this
`REACT_APP_SERVER_URL='http://vps-a******.*******:8800'` just this one line

and this is what i have in my dockefile

```
#you have to build the app manually first
# production environment

# pull official base image
FROM node:16-alpine AS node-build

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH


# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm i --force
#RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

RUN npm run build --force

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY /build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 6100
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

it doenst matter what i make in .env like change it to `localhost` or `141.****`it keeps always connecting to `vps-a******.*******:8800`

well if  i build the app manually and run `npm run build` in terminal then build the image it connects to whatever link i put in .env

i cant keep doing that(building the app locally before building the image)  because im working on a ci-cd pipline i want it to be done via docker file so how can i take .env in considartion while building the app using docker file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, be aware that I normally don't work with React, excuse me if I say something incorrect.

You mentioned `react-scripts` and the way your properties look like makes me think you are trying providing custom environment variables to your React application.

If you created your application with the `create-react-app` generator, as described in the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env), for this feature work properly you need to use an appropriate version of `react-scripts` and to create a `.env` file in your application root directory, and define in that file the appropriate variables. React will recognize all the environment variables starting with the `REACT_APP_` prefix. Exactly as you did.

These variables will be defined for on `process.env`. For example, in your use case, the environment variable `REACT_APP_SERVER_URL` will be exposed in your JS as `process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL`.

Be aware that `create-react-app` provides a simplification of the functionally exposed by [`dotenv`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv). Please, consider read [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579028/adding-an-env-file-to-react-project) for a more general use case explanation.

As indicated in the aforementioned documentation, is important to understand that generally:

> The environment variables are embedded during the build time.

i.e, it will replace the placeholders for your environments variables when compiling the application, when it generates your HTML, JS and CSS resources.

You are using a [docker multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to first, create your application bundle, and then deploy it to `nginx`.

I am assuming your are using a [stardard `create-react-app` directory structure](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/folder-structure/):

```
my-app/
  README.md
  .env
  node_modules/
  package.json
  public/
    index.html
    favicon.ico
  src/
    App.css
    App.js
    App.test.js
    index.css
    index.js
    logo.svg
```

Note I included the required `.env` file.

Your `Dockerfile` looks fine to me, although I tried to provide a simplified version, something like this:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:16-alpine AS node-build

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# install app dependencies, I normally do not use package-lock.json here
COPY package.json ./
# just, install the required stuff
RUN npm install

# now, build the app
# in this process is where the placeholders for your environment variables
# should be replaced by the information you defined inn your .env file
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./public ./public
# explicitly copy your .env file
COPY .env ./
# perform the actual build. this will generate a /build folder
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
# document where your app listen
EXPOSE 6100
# copy your nginx site configuration
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# I always prefer to clean the nginx default web directory before 
# copying the SPA output
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
# copy the contents of your /build folder from your node-build image
# to the nginx web root dir. note in the code snippet you provided in your
# question you are not doing this
COPY --from=node-build /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
# instruct your server to run in the foreground
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: i had some npm version problems... so thats why i took time to give u the answer and the bounty , but ur solution works perfectly thanks man !

Comment: You are very welcome @LouayGOURRIDA. I am very happy to hear that the proposed solution worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you have a .env file which your backend requires it in the code.

Any way, you could use the ENV method.
This will write your variable to the container on it's runtime.

```
#you have to build the app manually first
# production environment

# pull official base image
FROM node:16-alpine AS node-build

ENV REACT_APP_SERVER_URL='http://vps-a******.*******:8800'

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH


# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm i --force
#RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

RUN npm run build --force

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY /build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 6100
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: i tried but it still doesnt work , i noticed something that everytime i build the docker file it gives me an image with the same id , it always the same image id !

Comment: Than try to remove everything regarding and try again.

Comment: what you mean by everything ?

Comment: Docker prune your system - delete all images, volumes, networks.