# React Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, frontend, react-tsx

My app in react.ts contains the .env file to store variables with confidential data. But when using `process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID` an error appears in the console.

> *Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined*

How to solve? Help me please.

[image]

**.env file**

REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID = ed75ba30-1810

**authConfig.tsx file**

```
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
auth: {
    clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com,
},
```

[image]

Comment: process only defined in server side. Browser side has no definition of process

Comment: where is the `msalConfig` file located in your code file structure?

Comment: @Kaneki21 the msalConfig file are located in src -> authConfig.tsx. Why?

Comment: and where is the `.env` file located ? it has to be outside `src` folder

Comment: @Kaneki21 is out in the root of the project as recommended.

Answer (score 9):

Vite doesn't provide a built-in process variable like Node.js does. Vite is designed for frontend development and doesn't include a Node.js-like global object.

To access environment variables in Vite, you can use the **import.meta.env** object. This object allows you to access environment variables defined in your Vite project.

In your example, rename your variable in the env file as follows:

From:    REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID = ed75ba30-1810

To:  VITE_REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID = ed75ba30-1810

Make sure to prefix your environment variables with VITE_ when using Vite, as it automatically exposes variables starting with that prefix.

Your authConfig file should then be:

```
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
auth: {
    clientId: import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com,
},
```

Basically replace process.env with import.meta.env

Works really well.

Answer (score 6):

i am using vite react and i got the same error after searching everYthing which i have already done, still process is not define.

so i defined it in vite.config.js file by this

define: {'process.env': {}}

Comment: This pointed me to the right direction, but the better option for my case is  `define: {'process.env': process.env}`, credit : https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1973#issuecomment-815695512

Answer (score 3):

Vite reveals the env variable on the particular type of object called `import.meta.env` and provides some built-in variables in some cases:

- `import.meta.env.MODE`: The *mode* the app is running in(type *string*)
- `import.meta.env.BASE_URL`: the *base url* the app is being served from(type *string*)
- `import.meta.env.PROD`: whether the app is running in production mode(type *boolean*)
- `import.meta.env.DEV`: whether the app is running in development mode(type *boolean*)
- `import.meta.env.SSR`: whether the app is running in server(type *boolean*)

Vite uses *dotenv* package to load additional environment variables from the following files in your environment directory: like, `.env`, `.env.local`, `.env.[mode]` and `.env.[mode].local`.

> Note: An env file for a specific mode (*e.g. .env.production*) will
> take higher priority than a generic one (*e.g. .env*).
> env files are loaded at the start of Vite. Restart the server after making changes.

Only `VITE_SOME_KEY` will be exposed as `import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY` to your client source code, but `SOME_KEY` will not. Simply use in Vite,
`import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY` to get values, Otherwise it gets **undefined**. Also, Vite uses **dotenv-expand** to expand variables out of the box.

To know more exploring, you can check the vite doc - https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the environmental variables using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) (in server side) as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73854668/19099302) and get it into front end using [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) (if you need to use environmental variables in front end).

Answer (score 0):

like others said here, updating the vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {'process.env': process.env}
})
```

with `define: {'process.env': process.env}` that way you can also use process.env like normal rather than Bun.env, but it also did fix my issue where neither worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try with **npm run start** otherwise this should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49579700/9464846
Its always a config issue.

Comment: I did the steps and this error appeared in the console (Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at main.tsx:1:1).

Comment: Please try deleting node modules and running npm install

Answer (score -2):

You just need to update vite.config.ts file in React project as mentioned below in the link.

```
import { defineConfig,loadEnv } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig(({mode})=>{
  const env = loadEnv(mode,process.cwd(),'');
  return{
    define:{
      'process.env':env
    },
    plugins: [react()],
  }
})
```

Click [here](https://dev.to/boostup/uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined-12kg) which helped me in same scenario!