# Having issues with fetching an environment variable

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

In the root of my React project, I have this .env file containing the following.

```
DS_API_URL=[http://url.com](http:url.com/)
```

In another file of the project, an axios call utilizes this to return some stuff.

`const url = 'http://url.com/graph/tech-stack-by-role'` will return what I need.

`` const url = `${DS_API_URL}/graph/tech-stack-by-role`; `` returns an error.

How do I fetch the link from the env file and assign it to a var?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding an .env file to React Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579028/adding-an-env-file-to-react-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use environment variable in react you need to prefix the variable name with process.env.REACT_APP_. [Documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

So in your .env file you have:

```
REACT_APP_DS_API_URL=[http://url.com](http:url.com/)
```

Then to use:

```
const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_DS_API_URL}/graph/tech-stack-by-role`
```

Update to answer question:
update your start script to use the .env file you want. in this case it is .env.localhost. You will also need to npm install or yarn install env-cmd:

```
"start": "env-cmd -f ./.env.localhost react-scripts start",
```

Comment: I just attempted that. Upon doing a console log, it responds with the following...

GET http://localhost:3000/undefined/graph/tech-stack-by-role 404 (Not Found)