# React Firebase Error auth/invalid-api-key trying to use .env file

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to hook firebase to my react web app.
Everything works if I use the raw keys, which are directly sourced from firebase.config.js.
However, it does not work if I try to put raw keys in .env and use process.env to call it in firebase.config.

---

**Error that I'm getting in localhost:3000**

```
Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).
createErrorInternal
C:/Users/user1/src/core/util/assert.ts:142
  139 |   );
  140 | }
  141 | 
> 142 | return _DEFAULT_AUTH_ERROR_FACTORY.create(
      | ^  143 |   authOrCode,
  144 |   ...(rest as AuthErrorListParams<K>)
  145 | );
```

---

**in firebase.config.js**
v-- Raw key works fine.. but can't obv upload this to github..

```
// const firebaseConfig = {
//   apiKey: "raw key",
//   authDomain: "raw key",
//   projectId: "raw key",
//   storageBucket: "raw key",
//   messagingSenderId: "raw key",
//   appId: "raw key",
//   measurementId: "raw key"
// }
```

v-- I want to use this, but process.env doesn't work

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID 
}

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = app.firestore();
const auth = app.auth();

export { auth, firestore }
```

---

**in .env**

```
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY = raw key
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN = raw key
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL = raw key
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID = raw key
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET = raw key
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID = raw key
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID = raw key
REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID = raw key
```

---

**What I think is wrong, but do not know the solution to**
Based on messing around and many searches, I think the issue narrows down to auth
which means I need use initalizeApp with default values, but then do I create app2 with blank set of values? is this a good way to do it?

**Also another question..**
So people seem to use .env.local, but when I create .env.local, VSCode just recognize them as a regular textfile. Do I need to install some kind of npm?

I tried to make 2nd initializeApp.. with preloaded default value, but React is complaining that it's a duplicate and can't have 2 of these..

Comment: Try to restart the server, and theres no problem if vscode recognize it as a regular textfile you just need to install an extension for it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue.
The issue was that I had .env file inside of src folder,
when **it's supposed to be located outside of src folder (aka at root)**
Also had to restart the server to reflect the changes.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68945430/20362113

> **Steps to use environment variables in a CREATE REACT APP (Without
> dotenv package)**
>
> - Create a new file called `.env` in the **root** folder of the project (**NOT
>   inside src** folder but one level up. Remember, it should be at the same
>   level as package.json (**THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT!!**)
> - Define your variables like so (Note that every variable you define
>   should start with REACT_APP_)
>
>   Example : `.env file`
>
>   `REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY=8Sh9ZLwZevicWC-f_lmHvvyMu44cg3yZBU`
>
>   Note: You **don't** have to enclose the value in `"" or ''`
> - Now you can use the variable in any of your components like so
>
>   `const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY`
>
>   The name should match the key given in the `.env` file
> - Now before you try this out, **always remember to restart the local
>   server.** Once you run `npm start` it works. This step applies whenever
>   you make changes to the `.env` file. We generally forget this step so it
>   might not work.
> - Optionally, check if `.env` entry is present in `.gitignore` file. If the
>   entry of `.env` exists in `.gitignore` then your `.env` file will not be
>   pushed to github(This is the reason why we use `.env` in the first
>   place).