How to declare API Urls in a react application
I have built a react application which has a .env file where I have hardcoded the URLs. Now I have created a build package by using "npm run build prod".
This package has a main.js file which seems to have the URLs correctly mentioned.
I have further created a yml file (github workflow) which will create a build from git actions. But now I will not have a .env file
I have tried deploying this package to azure where I have declared the environment variables. But it does not seem to work. Looks like it is coming as undefined.
PS : I have to deploy this on multiple data centers and each will have a different URL for API
Code structure

Please create minimal reproducible example.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579028/adding-an-env-file-to-a-react-project
Use REACT_APP infront of your env variables
Eg:
REACT_APP_YOURKEY=value

REACT_APP_CD_API=value
i have this in my .env file
My code works as expected in local env. It is not working when I create a build from github workflow
