# How to secure the axios API key in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios

As you can see in the picture the API key is not protected and what is the solution?

[image]

Comment: One way is to do that I'm not sure it helps you but if you minify your js with webpack plugin then it might be easy better to secure your api.

Comment: You need to make a request with your server side language and use the api key on server instead of client. 1st you will need a route to make a request with axios /fetch/products/id and on that route you will make another request(the one from the picture) but with server side . Otherwise you can't really secure it

Comment: use the .env file on your project.
Take a look to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699820/how-do-i-hide-api-key-in-create-react-app