# Cannot load google-maps-react map when attempting to hide API key in a create-react-app using dotenv

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, create-react-app

I have a `create-react-app` that is using dotenv to hide a Google Maps API key, but when I try this I'm unable to get the map to load: I get an error saying `Google Maps API error: InvalidKeyMapError`. I was able to get this working before, but this was with the API key exposed.

Here's what I have in my files. In `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react'
require('dotenv').config()

const apiKey = `${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY}`
console.log(apiKey)

...

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
apiKey: apiKey,
})(App)
```

In my `.env` file I have: `REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY=myapikey`

In my app.js file I pass down the google props to my `MapContainer` component, which is in my render method, that loads the map itself. Is there some kind of conflict with dotenv and being able to read the `google-maps-react` API key?

I've already tried searching for the answer here and came across this: [How do I hide API key in create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699820/how-do-i-hide-api-key-in-create-react-app)

However even after restarting the server multiple times I get back the same error as well as `undefined` for the `console.log(apiKey)`.

Comment: You don't need `require('dotenv').config()` if you are using `create-react-app`, I believe. Have you tried removing that?

Comment: @Tholle I tried that just now and still receive the same error. If I remove that line from `App.js` would I then need to change my `.env` in some way, like the format and possibly exporting it as a config object? Or should it be fine the way I already have it formatted?

Comment: It should be fine with a single line of text `REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY=myapikey`. Very odd. What version of `create-react-app` did you use to create the project with? [`.env` support was added in 1.1.0](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/CHANGELOG.md#110-january-15-2018).

Comment: @Tholle I'm using version `1.0.0` of `create-react-app`. I'm also using version `15.6.1` of `react`. Ah, so I should try upgrading with that version and then give it another go?

Comment: It might work, I'm not sure. [This](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#updating-to-new-releases) indicates that you only have to update `react-scripts`: "In most cases bumping the `react-scripts` version in `package.json` and running `npm install` in this folder should be enough, but it’s good to consult the changelog for potential breaking changes."

Comment: @Tholle Ah, I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. I went through the changelog and ran the migration command `yarn add --exact react-scripts@1.1.4`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this there is an alternative library called google-map-react (missing the "s") which seems to work fine with .env variables

https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react