# What is the preferable way to hide private information in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, environment-variables, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to hide private information like API key when uploading my project. So I am wondering if there's a way to set environment variable somewhere as I do in command prompt.

For example, I want to hide my API key in `google_maps_api.xml`

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">API_KEY_HERE</string>
```

How can I do it in Android Studio?

Comment: uploading project on what ?

Comment: I mean I am going to upload my project on GitHub.

Comment: Just remove your api key, whosoever that needs to use your project should go and get an API key from google with their account credentials

Comment: You mean I should remove my API key part every time I push my project into GitHub?

Comment: Or maybe I should add `google_maps_api.xml` to `gitignore`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as per the best practices it is recommended to keep all the credentials in `gradle.properties` like this:

```
KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=password123
KEY_PASSWORD=password789
GOOGLE_MAP_KEY=API_KEY_HERE
```

This file is automatically imported by Gradle, so you can use it like:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        try {
            storeFile file("myapp.keystore")
            storePassword KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias "thekey"
            keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
        }
        catch (ex) {
            throw new InvalidUserDataException("You should define KEYSTORE_PASSWORD and KEY_PASSWORD in gradle.properties.")
        }
    }
}
```

To use `gradle.properties` inside a class you can refer this:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        // defining the google map key
        buildConfigField "String", "GOOGLE_MAP_KEY", MAP_KEY
    }
}
```

This will be generated in `<package_name>.BuildConfig.java` and would contain these fields:

```
public class BuildConfig {
    // ... other generated fields ...
    public static final String GOOGLE_MAP_KEY = "API_KEY";
}
```

You can now directly use GOOGLE_MAP_KEY by calling `BuildConfig.GOOGLE_MAP_KEY` in any class.

> In order to keep all your credentials safe do not commit **gradle.properties** in your version control repositories like Github etc.

Comment: So in my case, I should just write down my API key in `gradle.properties` and replace my key with a variable in `google_maps_api.xml`?

Comment: If you want to use the key in XML then first you need to do the setup like I have shown above of GOOGLE_MAP_KEY in `build.gradle` and after Sync when it will be generated in BuildConfig, then you can access it as other resources like @string/GOOGLE_MAP_KEY

Comment: For more details read this article as well [link](https://medium.com/code-better/hiding-api-keys-from-your-android-repository-b23f5598b906)

Comment: I ended up just adding `google_maps_api.xml` to `gitignore` because the key that Android Studio gave me is referred to like `@string/google_maps_api_key`  in `ANdroidMaifest.xml`.
But thanks for this tip. It is helpful.

Comment: Glad, it helped :)

Comment: please decompiled apk the api key will be visable this is not working

Comment: Yes agreed, so the solution provided in this answer works for not exposing your secrets from your version control system, but since they are part of your application, they can still be discovered by decompiling your APK, as per my understanding we can restrict the API key through various parameters, so even if it is exposed it won’t be used by anyone.

Answer (score -2):

First, you should make .env file outside of your src folder.

Then, add

```
REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY=123456
```

Replace 123456 with your `API_KEY`

Before commit, you should exclude this **.env** file so find `.gitignore` file and add .env.

you can use these env variables like this..

```
 const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY;
```

Now you're free to go.

Don't forget to add .env in .gitignore file.

for more info  [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699820/how-do-i-hide-api-key-in-create-react-app)

Comment: This is for Node.js environment, not for Android.