# Hiding API Key in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, create-react-app

I'd like to start by saying I followed all of the suggestions here [How do I hide API key in create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699820/how-do-i-hide-api-key-in-create-react-app/50457996) but none of them worked.  I've searched for over an hour trying to find an answer but nothing.  Below is my explanation.

1. I used `create-react-app` to scaffold my project
2. I'm using Google Maps and have not used any other API's yet
3. I created a `.env` file in the root of my project
4. In that file I added `REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = api key`
5. In my component file `Map.js` I added `const GM_API_KEY =` `${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY};` (the tick marks are around this variable in my file but they won't show up here)
6. In my url for the map, I added the key like so `"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GM_API_KEY&callback=initMap"`
7. Also, at the top of my `Map.js` file I added a `console.log(GM_API_KEY);`
    to ensure it was working.
8. I exported my Map component and then imported it in my `App.js`
9. I restarted my server

When the page loads, my key is output in the console, but I still get an error from Google saying my API key is invalid.  Also, if I manually `console.log(GM_API_KEY)` after the page has loaded I get a reference error saying that `GM_API_KEY is undefined`

If anyone has any suggestions or can provide any help I would greatly appreciate it!  Thank you for taking time to check out my question.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] to go along with your English description.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the guidelines and my apologies for not providing that.  Here is my example that worked for others in the future:

In `.env` file: `REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = api key here `

In my `Map.js` component: `const GM_API_KEY =` `'${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}';` (use back ticks instead of quotes to surround all of this)

In the url call: `'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${GM_API_KEY}&callback=initMap'` (use back ticks around this as well instead of quotes)

Comment: No need to apologize. Just [edit] your question to include the requested information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to define the constant that holds the api key in a lifecycle hook like componentWillMount (though this method is now unsafe) to ensure that the variable is available when the component mounts:

`componentWillMount() {
    const GM_API_KEY = ${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY};
}`

Then

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${GM_API_KEY}&callback=initMap`

Comment: I did this except I added the tick marks around my URL where as previously I was only inserting the variable into the URL.  So my URL is now `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${GM_API_KEY}&callback=initMap` whereas previously I had double quotes around my url and had forgotten to include the `${}`

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

What I do with sensitive data is not even saving them in `.env` I open the terminal inside the root of my project and run `export API_KEY=sdf54vvetvf...` and then inside your app you can access it through `process.env.API_KEY` *note* you need to add it manually each time you close the terminal from that session

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will definitely give this a go in the future!

Comment: "note you need to add it manually each time you close the terminal from that session" or set it in .bashrc

Comment: @Code-Apprentice true but i prefer to keep it "per project" (: lets say I have couple of projects with diff GOOGLE_API? .bashrc wont be a good idea in that case

Comment: @obiwankenoobi good point. Some other bash script to automate each project will be helpful in such a case.

Comment: wouldn't it still end up in the DOM?