# how to hide google maps token in react app?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=sdfjwsdfjdlsfj_uyMO-9Ckljklfb4_DC-k_uqU&libraries=places"></script>

    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
```

This is what I need to put in my index.html file in order for my react app to access the google maps API.

How do i hide the token?

Comment: What library are you using?

Answer (score -2):

1.[It was answered there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668940/hiding-api-key-in-react)
2.[And there](https://www.reddit.com/r/react/comments/qcork2/hiding_google_maps_javascript_api_key_on_react/)

In short: it's public key and it's designed to be used like this