# How to handle an API key in a React frontend without users having to login

Tags: reactjs, azure, security, azure-functions

I'm building a React frontend which calls several Azure Functions API's. Users don't have to login. Now I have a host key, which I include in the requests to the functions, but sending this api key to the client-side doesn't feel very secure. Now I know that I can use process.env, but that still isn't very secure I think.

Is there a way to do this securely?

Thanks!

Comment: see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699820/how-do-i-hide-api-key-in-create-react-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple rule: Nothing can be kept secret in an Angular/React SPA that is executed on the client side.

You could go down the path of server-side rendering of your React app, call the Azure Function API on a server and only return already rendered pages to the user. That way your users don't see keys but of course they still cause API calls with every page load.