# How to hide API Keys in React public html file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to use the EmailJS service to send info from a contact form. However, I have several issues

1. In the head section should add the following script

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            emailjs.init('my-token');
        })();
    </script>
   ```

How can I hide that token? I have tried storing it in the `.env` file and accessing it with

```
emailjs.init(`${process.env.REACT_APP_INIT_KEY}`);
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: the only way to store API key is in backend language like nodejs ,php, etc.

Comment: relevant answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699820/how-do-i-hide-api-key-in-create-react-app#answer-57103663

Comment: Hi @RobinHood thanks for sharing the relevant answer, which makes sense. I will look into that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide an API key in Create React App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699820/how-do-i-hide-an-api-key-in-create-react-app)

Answer (score 1):

**You shouldn't**. Secrets should be kept on the backend.

Using JavaScript obfuscation techniques to hide an API key on the frontend won't protect it.

Answer (score 0):

Create index.js file at the same level of your html file, and put this statement in it `emailjs.init('my-token');`, then call this file in your html page.

your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     (function() {
         emailjs.init('my-token');
     })();
 </script>
```

the solution:

in index.js file

```
function() {
         emailjs.init('my-token');
     })();
```

call it in Html file

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: This absolutely won't hide the token