# how to hide API key in react app using .env file

Tags: reactjs, api, hide, github-pages

my question if **we host react app on github page**s  and put apikey in **.env file** it's going to work or not or any other better method of hiding api key.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699820/how-do-i-hide-api-key-in-create-react-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a .env file would not work, as its purpose is to **not be included in the version controlled repository**. Instead, I would recommend to use a .env file while developing **locally** and then host it in Vercel or Netlify, which both support environment variables. With that said, you still shouldn't really be accessing APIs from your frontend, especially with API keys, and should instead be accessing them from the backend.