# React Native - Securely storing

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, api

I have a `React-Native` app, and I have a PHP-backend server.
Now I'm trying to use my `SMTP Password` in my `react-native` app, so I can send email easily, [react-native-smtp-mailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-smtp-mailer).

As I saw in other questions [(How do I hide API key in create-react-app?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699820/how-do-i-hide-api-key-in-create-react-app), It is not a good idea to store it inside my `.env file` because React environment variables are embedded in the build and are publicly accessible.

However, there is an option to use my backend server to get my `API key/Password`.

> You should really only save API keys or secrets in your backend such as Node / Express. You can have your client send a request to your backend API, which can then make the actual API call with the API key and send the data back to your client.

But I can't understand how to do it. If I'm creating an API call, but it's very easy to access it from `Postman` or something similar.
For example, I have `http://api.com/getPass` and it gives me my `API key/Password` however everyone can access it.

### So my question is...

**How Do I Do it** to work secretly.
(It would be much easier if you can provide a Code example.)
Or should I do the emailing on my server side? (I Have to send Multiple images).
But If I do it on my server side, everyone with the `"URL"` can access it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the `expo-secure-store` module to your application which will give you a place to store the password and access it when needed without having to store it hard-coded in your source code. You could then provide an input element within the application where you could enter it once, saving it under a certain key in the store, and accessing it via that key when needed. It doesn't give you a place to permanently save it as part of the code, but the data would persist across launches.

Comment: I'm not using expo for my react-native app.

Comment: Using Expo to manage your project is not required to use Expo modules. You may install Expo packages in any React Native application. See this [link](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/) and this [article](https://blog.expo.dev/embracing-expo-modules-in-your-react-native-projects-cd8ed4cbec3)

Comment: There are also other 3rd-party alternatives if you prefer not to use Expo at all, as explained in the RN docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/security).

Comment: Good to know that I can use Expo modules. Thanks!

Comment: @Xacoio Please mark my answer as correct if it has helped solve your problem. :D