# Reactjs 18.2 I can't get value from .env file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, .env

I want get value from .env file on reactjs 18.2.
`REACT_APP_API_URL = localhost:4000`

My code is on app.js 9-line => `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL);`

```
import "./App.css";

import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import Routers from "./Router";

function App() {

  console.log("======================");

  console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL);

  console.log("======================");

  return (

    <Router>

      <Routers />

    </Router>

  );

}

export default App;
```

But browser return me on console **Undefined**

[image: This is picture from browser]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide an API key in Create React App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699820/how-do-i-hide-an-api-key-in-create-react-app)

Comment: Is there an error? If so, please share the same. Also what is this supposed to lead to?

Comment: Are you rebuilding the project, `npm start`?

Comment: Yes I'm rebuilded the project

Comment: What bundler are you using? CRA? Vite?

Comment: I'm using CRA bundler

Comment: Can you try to quote and remove space in the env to `REACT_APP_API_URL="localhost:4000"`